# Xillinx VHDL code error

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to write a vhdl code am it gives me more am trying to write a code for a sequential with 5 states ( S0 , S1 , S2 , S3 , S4)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Seqq is
PORT ( seq , clk , reset : IN std_logic;
       output : OUT std_logic;
         leds : OUT std_logic_vector( 2 downto 0) );
end Seqq;


architecture Behavioral of Seqq is
type states IS ( S0 , S1 , S2 , S3 , S4);
signal nxt , prst : states ;
begin
FB:PROCESS(reset, clk)
begin
if Rising_edge(clk) then
 if reset = '1' then prst <='0';

else prst <= nxt ;
end if ;
end if ;
end process FB;comb:PROCESS( prst) 
begin 
case prst IS 
when S0 =>
If seq = '0' then nxt <= S0;
elsif seq = '1' then nxt <= S1;
end if ;
leds <= "000";
output <= '0';

when S1 =>
If seq = '0' then nxt <= S2;
elsif seq = '1' then nxt <= S1;
end if ;
leds <= "001";
output <= '0';

when S2 =>
If seq = '0' then nxt <= S2;
elsif seq = '1' then nxt <= S1;
end if ;
leds <= "010";
output <= '0';

when S3 =>
If seq = '0' then nxt <= S0;
elsif seq = '1' then nxt <= S4;
end if ;
leds <= "011";
output <= '0';

when S4 =>
If seq = '0' then nxt <= S0;
output <= '1';
elsif seq = '1' then nxt <= S1;
end if ;
leds <= "100";
output <= '0';
end case ;
end process comb;


end Behavioral;
```

and the error which I get is

```
Type of prst is incompatible with type of '0'.
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
if reset = '1' then prst <='0';
```

you are assigning a `'0'` to prst. If you look at your error message `prst is incompatible with type of '0'`, you will see that the types don't match.

Investigating your type of prst, you will see that it is of type `states`, an enum ranging from `S0` to `S4`. '0' however is of type `std_logic` or `bit`, which is not convertible to `state`.

So, what you propably want (if it is still ok with your logic) is to change assignment of `prst` to `S0` instead:

```
if reset = '1' then prst <= S0;
```